# Webpage not loading in the Android browser

Tags: browser, pdf, stock-browser

I was checking out my website using the default Android (2.3.4) browser and the link to one of my PDFs is not loading and returns a "Web page not available" error.  The URL http://www.ericperrets.info/Resume%20-%20Eric%20Perret.pdf .  When I try it in Chrome or any other browsers on the desktop it load correctly.  Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a similar issue has been raised in the Google code repository for android at: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3678

I've just tested this with a few browsers on Gingerbread - namely Firefox, Dolphin HD and the native browser. Neither of them like to navigate to the file directly, but accessing the file through search results (e.g. Google) seem to prompt the browser to download the file.

It may be worth cross-checking the configuration for the PDF mime-type on your web server. The standard MIME type is application/pdf.

Answer (score 2):

For better compatibility you might consider removing the spaces in the filename. Other than that I don't know what the problem could be.

Comment: That would be the first thing I'd check. In my experience spaces, escaped or not, are inconsistently managed across browsers and OSes.